# Matrix that satisfies an equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

We know that $A\in M_{m n}(\mathbb R)\land B\in M_{n m}(\mathbb R)$ where $2\leq n\leq m\leq 3$.

If $4(AB)^3+3(AB)^2+2(AB)+I_m=0_m$, which one of the following holds?:

$(a)$$m=2$

$(b)$ $m=3$

$(c)$ $n=2$

$(d)$ $m=n$

$(e)$ $(AB)^4=I_m$

$(f)$ $\det(AB)=0$

$n=2$ or $m=n$ don't seem to change anything in the equality.

We can rewrite the given equality as $AB(-4(AB)^2-3(AB)-2I_m)=I_m$, which means that AB is nonsingular, so $f$ is ruled out. The most logical answer to me seems to be e), but I didn't manage to prove it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Square matrices?

Comment: Actually I'm quite sure that's not correct. A is an m by n matrix and B is an n by m matrix, therefore their product(AB) is an m by m matrix, which is a square matrix no matter what m and n are.

Comment: No idea about $m=3$. And no idea what you were trying to say in your comment, to be honest. I don't see how the fact that $m=n$ or not impacts the equality. The determinant exists either way. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why doesn't e not hold?

Comment: Well, $(AB)^2$=$-4/3(AB)^3-2/3(AB)-1/3I_m$, and $AB=-2(AB)^3-3/2(AB)^2-1/2I_m$

Comment: Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Sorry for word choice, I'm a foreign student, so $(e)\implies (AB)^2=I_m$, then you have two cases (because of the real vector space); $I_m\&  -I_m$.

Comment: Also, what you said, for the type of the matrices (which, of course, doesn't have to be the same, but it also satisfies the condition) will be important for the proof that for (arbitrary) $AB=C_n \& BA=D_m,\;\; tr(C_n)=tr(D_m)$ This task is an excellent example  I work with at the moment, too.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker either. I'm in the last year of highschool now. I solved my first integral a couple months ago :)
This is the first time I heard of vector spaces, I suppose I'll learn about them at uni. I read about the trace property that you mentioned, but thought it only works if AB and BA are of the same order, which would imply that A and B had to be of the same order.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $I_m$ and $-I_m$ would be the only posibilities if e holds, but let's leave that aside. We have $m=2$ and $m=3$ left.
I know that any square matrix satisfies it's characteristic polynomial, but we were only given the formula for a 2x2 matrix, and I didn't fully understand how it works in the general case. I suppose I could use that to maybe rule out m=2?

Comment: That is great, do you know how to multiply matrices? You can use a formula for an element on the main diagonal (if I said it correctly), let's say: $C=(c_{i j})\& D=(d_{i j})$ $\;\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_{i j}b_{j i}=\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_{j i} a_{i j} $ These elements behave like scalars if they are all real. If $(e)$ holded, the sqaure root of the aquare would be $I_m$ or $-I_m$. And, when you take it, it appears not to equal I_m in the equality. You can exponentiate (if correctly said), that is allowed.

Comment: Your MathJax seems to have gotten messed up.

Comment: The dimension is not important (as long as it satisfies the constraint), that is the beauty, and this type of matrices are a subject of many wonderful articles. I hope my comments were of some use, I still have to improve my explaining skills (as Feynman says).

Comment: Well, at least now I know a couple of things I didn't know earlier on. You're certainly better than me at explaining things :) Thanks for everything. I'll think about this a little more tomorrow.

Comment: You're welcome, don't think your less good just because you're younger. Actually, your mind is fresher than mine, and use it!

Comment: Thanks for your kind words :)

Comment: I recently learned about cyclic permutations so you might find this interesting, also the way of thinking about certain group in this case like an equivalence class:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474812/how-to-prove-the-cyclic-property-of-the-trace