# $n$ different factors give at most $(n-1)!$ different traces vs. cyclic permutations property

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

At the very beginning, I will refer to this post:[How to prove the cyclic property of the trace?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1474812/how-to-prove-the-cyclic-property-of-the-trace) which is a starting point for my question:

> If cyclic permutations don't change $tr(A_1\cdot A_2\ldots A_n),$ prove
>   that $n\;\text{factors}$ give at most $(n-1)!$ different traces.

My attempt:
$$\text{cyclic permutation}\iff \text{initial trace}$$
$$\implies\text{number of non-cyclic permutations}=?$$
By the assumption and the proof I've seen on the link above:
$$tr(A_1\cdot\underbrace{ A_2\ldots A_{n-1}}_{X} A_n)=tr(A_n\cdot A_1\cdot X)$$
$X$ consists of $(n-2)$ factors $\implies$ $(n-2)!-1$ non-cyclic permutations 'in' $X$, but I haven't achieved anything this way.

Then I considered derangements, but it wasn' t a very clear idea because I didn't know what to do with the order of factors with consecutive indexes and then I thought of a proof by induction, but after proving the base it didn't seem sufficient either.

Comment: Write out the 24 permutations of $A_1\cdot A_2\cdot A_3\cdot A_4$.  Group together the ones that the cyclic property tells you must be equal.  How many groups are there?  What is the general principle here?

Comment: @WillOrrick, so, I should get something like 'classes'?

Comment: Yes. Define two products to be equivalent when their factors differ by cyclic permutation. Equivalence classes then have size $n$. The largest number of different traces occurs when each equivalence class gives a different trace.

Comment: @WillOrrick, thank you very much!